# Using triggers to avoid duplication when not deferring unique constraints. (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, triggers

PostgreSQL  11.1

I have a unique constraint as:

```
CONSTRAINT unique_service UNIQUE (patient_recid, tservice, procedure_recid)
```

I would like to continue to use UPSERT with ON CONFLICT so can't defer the unique constraint.

Using a trigger as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_service()
   RETURNS TRIGGER
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
     IF NEW.patient_recid <> OLD.patient_recid  THEN
            DELETE FROM service WHERE recid = OLD.recid;
     END IF;    
     RETURN NEW;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER merge_service
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON service
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (NEW.patient_recid <> OLD.patient_recid)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_service();
```

I get the error:
**ERROR:  tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command**

At the application level, I would like to do something simple like this without violating the unique constraint:

```
UPDATE service
SET patient_recid = 15478
WHERE patient_recid = 23262;
```

Assuming I have complete control over both the database and the application, what do I need to do to make this work withough deferring the unique constraint?

TIA

Comment: In the `IF` statement use `RETURN NULL;`, then the `UPDATE` will not occur.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  Thanks! It works now. :)